# Magento Product Order Report add custom filter

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to extend Product Ordered Report In magento using the following [Add more filters in report the products ordered - Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946490/add-more-filters-in-report-the-products-ordered-magento) ..
But unfortnately , I am not able to get the order status as field in product order report. Please can anyone guide me through it as to why the filter block is not working ?

Comment: Anyone please guide me on this...

Comment: Please help me in overrriding the product report. thanks.